# What's the difference between isinglass and gelatin?

Tags: finings, gelatin, isinglass

For one I have read that if after the yeast is settled and the yeast is stirred up (for whatever reason) then gelatin will not help dropping the yeast out while isinglass will. Also I've read the complete opposite. Which one is true? Of course as I've read both I'd expect a good source for the claim.

Are there other differences between them? More than ethic/religious aspect of sourcing the collagen (I assume that pig gelatin is not kosher for example).

Comment: Where have you read this? In particular, homebrew forums or articles? The lack of legitimate, sourced answers and prevalence of opinion have pretty much left me to only trust SE (at least when sourced) or source articles, but even then you can find disagreement.

Comment: @Wyrmwood I don't remember, but obviously at least one of them didn't have a source, probably none of them. That's why I ank for an answer with a good source for the claim - just receiving yet another contradictive unsourced statement doesn't help sorting the confusion out.

Answer (score 4):

Looking around on the internet it seems that both do the same. Both products contain collagen, which bind to yeast and proteins.

The main difference is that for using gelatin the beer must be cold. For isinglass this is not necessary, but using isinglass is more difficult: the pH of the isinglass mix needs to be adjusted, and the isinglass mix needs also to be put in the fridge for a couple of days before adding it to the beer.

[Finings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finings)

[Isinglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isinglass)

[Culinary uses of gelatin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelatin#Culinary_uses): According to this, isinglass used to be a source of gelatin.

[How to use isinglass to fine beer](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/showpost.php?p=837357&postcount=6)

[How to clear your beer with gelatin](http://www.bertusbrewery.com/2012/06/how-to-clear-your-beer-with-gelatin.html)

Comment: Do you have a source for your claims? Note that "just looking around the internetz" is no good source as we can find out there that the earth is a flat, spherical object that is the center of the universe circulating the sun etc etc.